# variable value changed simulateously by different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, simultaneous

I have many concurrent running http request serving threads. They will be creating an Object(? extends Object) for every request and save the object in a list. 
Advice me some good data structure to implement this list.
I can't use ArrayList since it was not thread safe.
I dont like to use Vector - since its synchronized, it will make other threads to wait when one of the http thread was saving the object.
Also tried LinkedList, but there is  data loss due to concurrent update.

Comment: Yes, you should use synchronization. Your concern about speed is called "premature optimization". Your other option is using one of the atomics from the concurrent package that use CAS.

Comment: What do you mean by simultaneous? In the same clock cycle? What do you mean by updated? In the CPU memory, the L1 cache, the L2 cache or the main memory? The only way to have a consistent view is to use locking of some kind.  Otherwise your question doesn't really mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable would need to be atomic so that it can safely be updated by multiple threads (see java.util.concurrent.atomic).  You could also use an AtomicInteger to keep track of the number of times the variable is updated.

But are you sure you want do this without explicitly controlling the update to a variable?